# how to set docker_opts on windows

Tags: docker

I want to use the third-party's images and book says that I should add the configuration

`--insecure-registry=hub.ghostcloud.cn`

to `Docker_OPTS` under `/etc/default/docker`.

I am using the `windows7 64bit` and docker is installed by using `docker toolbox`. But I cannot find the `/etc/default/docker` file.

So where is the file's directroy?  And how can I set the `Docker_OPTS` to use third-party's images on windows? Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Windows, Docker runs inside a VM. So, you have to ssh into the VM and make the changes. To ssh into the VM (assuming `default` is the VM name you have created using Docker toolbox), enter the following command in the Docker Quickstart Terminal,

```
docker-machine ssh default
```

Once you ssh into the VM, then look into the file /var/lib/boot2docker/profile, and you will find the `"DOCKER_OPTS=..."`. Just add `--insecure-registry=hub.ghostcloud.cn` to that. You are all set.

In case, if you have trouble in using `cd` command to enter into `/var/lib/boot2docker` directory, you may want change yourself as a sudo user. Execute the following command,

```
sudo -i
```

Comment: When I ssh into the VM, it shows `docker@default: ~$`, and then how can I look into the file by input what command? I use `cd var`, but it shows `can't cd to var`. Thank you.

Comment: I have edited my answer assuming you actually got permission denied error message.

Comment: Thank you. I still have a question: after I enter to the `/var/lib/boot2docker`, what command should I input to set configuration?

Comment: You should use vi editor or nano to edit the file `profile`. Something you have to Google how to use. It's too much to explain in this post. Check http://www.howtogeek.com/102468/a-beginners-guide-to-editing-text-files-with-vi/

Comment: could not find DOCKER_OPTS parameter in profile file